# Spark partitioning of related data into row groups

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

With [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) we can partition a dataframe into separate files when saving into Parquet format.

In [the way Parquet files are written](http://cloudsqale.com/2020/05/29/how-parquet-files-are-written-row-groups-pages-required-memory-and-flush-operations/), each partition contains multiple row groups each of include column statistics pertaining to each group (e.g., min/max values, as well as number of `NULL` values).

Now, it would seem ideal in some situations to organize the Parquet file such that related data appears together in one or more row groups. This would be a secondary level of partitioning *within* each partition file (which constitutes the first level).

This is possible using for example [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html#pyarrow-parquet-write-table), but how can we do this with a distributed SQL engine such as Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides partitioning you can order your data to group related data together in a limited set of partitions. Statement from [Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html):

> Z-Ordering is a technique to colocate related information in the same
> set of files

```py
(
    df
    .write.option("header", True)
    .orderBy(df.col_1.desc())
    .partitionBy("col_2")
)
```

Comment: Of course! So simple, yet so effective.